# How do I make a system message appear with Javascript with the right CSS?

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a system message appear using Javascript. I have used the following code so far to make the system message appear:

```
  var jmsgs = ['Deletion cancelled - no records deleted.'];
  Joomla.renderMessages({'alert': jmsgs });
```

This almost works as I want it. The message appears but the styling isn't working. This is how it is displaying.

[image: Javascript system message]

Normally when I use PHP to make the system messages appear they have CSS styling applied, eg using the following code:

```
$msg = 'Very helpful message';
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($msg, 'message');
```

This is how it looks using PHP and how I want it to look using Javascript.
[image: PHP system message]

Is there a way I can make Javascript display the system message so the styling is applied?

Comment: It looks like your template is overriding the styling for the enqueue messages. I would suggest looking at the HTML markup difference first

Comment: Thanks @Lodder. I've had a look at the HTML and the javascript version is producing quite different markup so it explains the differences. But I have no idea what to do about it or how to get the javascript to product the same mark up as PHP...

Comment: Which template are you using? Could you provide a link to the template download page?

Comment: I am using a custom template at the moment @Lodder but will have a go with protostar and see if I can figure it out. Thanks